# why the vm JAVA_OPTIONS does not work in jetty

Tags: java, shell, jvm, sh, jvm-arguments

I'm not familiar with shell, maybe this stucked me but I don't know what causes this issue.
When develop a web program with jetty 8.1.13 container, in start.ini file I add some arguments
as(reference from https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/enable-remote-debugging.html )

```html
--exec
-Xdebug
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n
```

and in jetty.sh file I add some -D vm options something like

```html
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dargs=switch"
export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

and then I start the jetty through

```
bin/jetty.sh start
```

then the shell create two process,
through command

```
ps aux | grep jetty
```

we found the two process, like

```
lawrence         26180   0.0 12.3  8900580 1034116 s000  S    11:03下午   1:13.71 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n -Xmx2000m -Xmn512m -Djetty.home=/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13 -cp /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-xml-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-http-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-server-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-security-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-servlet-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-webapp-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-deploy-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-servlets-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-annotations-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-1.1.0.v201108011116.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/annotations/org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.v200803061910.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-jmx-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jsp/com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jsp/javax.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-jndi-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-plus-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jndi/javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/resources:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-websocket-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-util-8.1.13.v20130916.jar:/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/lib/jetty-io-8.1.13.v20130916.jar org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration /var/folders/tl/dy87zyw579ggfx32tlv8tn3r0000gn/T/start8991351085930913981.properties /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty.xml /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty-annotations.xml /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty-deploy.xml /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty-webapps.xml /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty-contexts.xml /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty-testrealm.xml /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty-logging.xml /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/etc/jetty-started.xml
lawrence         26177   0.0  0.2  7864928  19696 s000  S    11:03下午   0:01.30 /usr/bin/java -Dargs=switch -Djetty.state=/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/jetty.state -Djetty.home=/Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/tl/dy87zyw579ggfx32tlv8tn3r0000gn/T/ -jar /Users/lawrence/tools/jetty-dist-8.1.13/start.jar etc/jetty-logging.xml etc/jetty-started.xml
```

the args=switch jvm option should be read as expected in the main process 26177, but it's a pity that it did not.

so, what this command actually do when we use --exec parameter to fork() a new child process, why this shell cannot read the -D jvm options even the -D jvm options in the command line ?
Anyone please help to resolve this issue?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you used -Dkey=value names on the java command line (before the main-class), then those will not be forwarded to the forked JVM.
But if you used the -Dkey=value after the main-class, or in the ${jetty.base}/start.ini file then those system properties will forward to the forked JVM.